# Hierarchical Clustering in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, hierarchical-clustering

I need to use Agglomerative Hierarchical Clustering in OpenCV. When I searched the documentation, I found the following function.
But it uses hierarchical k-means. k-means is a different technique. In theory, we study both as different clustering techniques. 
How is hierarchical k-means different from hierarchical clustering?

[Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/flann/doc/flann_clustering.html#flann-hierarchicalclustering-distance)

I need to cluster some specific spatial locations within an image. Result is used for recognizing some objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Agglomerative Clustering](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/hierarchical-agglomerative-clustering-1.html) is bottom-up clustering, and [Divisive Clustering](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/divisive-clustering-1.html#sec:divisive) is top-down clustering. K-means is a flat clustering algorithm.

Given the characteristic of k-means, hierarchical K-means tree would be likely a top-down clustering.

So, I venture that opencv::flann::hierarchicalClustering is top-down clustering.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any function in  OpenCV library for agglomerative clustering?

Comment: Sorry, that, I don't know.